# How to group these arrays accordingly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I'm using PDO to run a mysql query with 2 joins and this is the result I get from the database:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 489
        [cluster_id] => 
        [label_value_id] => 4
        [label_id] => 1
        [int_value] => 40
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 489
        [cluster_id] => 
        [label_value_id] => 6
        [label_id] => 2
        [int_value] => 20
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 489
        [cluster_id] => 
        [label_value_id] => 9
        [label_id] => 3
        [int_value] => 10
    )

)
```

The idea is that there will be multiple id's later on but for simplicities sake I only have 1 entry with id 489 for now.

I need the 3 arrays (cause of the joins) to be 1 array that looks something like this, I want a subarray based on the label-value_id => int_value relationship:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 489
        [cluster_id] => 
        [label_value_id] => 4
        [label_id] => 1
        [int_value] => 40
        [vector_data] => Array
        (
            [4] => 40
            [6] => 20
            [9] => 10
        )
    )
)
```

I'd rather have this done in the PHP and not the Query because I dont have control over the queries when I implement this into the live application.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: how do you want `label_id` then ?

Comment: what is your sql query ?

Comment: You will need to iterate the array. Inside the loop compare the label value id and if match add another array to it with the key vector data.

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal label_id is irrelevant at this point. Usable answer is provided by Ghost

Comment: Did you try `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`?

Comment: There is a FETCH_GROUP?! I'll try that tomorrow. That might actually give a performance boost on my algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another container for gathering all batches which share the same id using its keys to transfer them. On initialization, create another container for that `vector`, then just push them line any normal array value:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    // initialization
    if(!isset($result[$values['id']])) {
        $result[$values['id']] = $values;
    }

    $result[$values['id']]['vector_data'][$values['label_value_id']] = $values['int_value'];
}

// $result = array_values($result); // optional key reindex
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/LGVQKE)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works as intended with multiple id's as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Jebble yes, it will work on that as well. im glad this helped

Comment: I see now that I had exactly this except for your !isset check which is so logical now!

Comment: @Jebble yes, you'll only need to set the group once

Comment: What about `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak no, it won't group that, `vector_data` is a group of elements, not a group of batches

Answer (score 0):

You can process your array from DB like this:

```
$pdo = array(
    array(
        "id" => 489,
        "label_value_id" => 4,
        "int_value" => 40,
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 489,
        "label_value_id" => 6,
        "int_value" => 20,
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 489,
        "label_value_id" => 9,
        "int_value" => 10,
    ),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($pdo as $array) {
    if (!isset($result[$array['id']])) {
        $result[$array['id']] = array(
            "id" => $array['id'],
            "vector_data" => array()
        );
    }

    $result[$array['id']]['vector_data'][$array['label_value_id']] = $array['int_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, and i solve it through PDO.
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) available examples. I reach same result with code:

```
$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

think you should try it...

Comment: PDO::FETCH_GROUP does not provide the wanted result.

Comment: It's a pity) but maybe need to juggling with fields... because it's very convenient...

Comment: It is indeed, but for what I needed it was not a viable solution. Ghost has already given the solution.

Comment: It's better because it just select already prepared data, and no need to process data through foreach...